# Start an app with URI

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe, uri

Windows Apps are in C:\Program Files\WindowsApps. Windows Apps are a particular type of app. Not normal Windows' programs.

These are newer programs like Mail, Weather, and Calculator.

To start them you use a URL. EG to start calculator you type **calculator://.**

Did I want to start **Quick Assist** like the **calculator://**

But Quick-Assist:// is not working...

Any ideas?

Comment: "To start them you use a URL." – Not in general, no.

Comment: Just curious, why this is tagged PowerShell? It's not a PowerShell code issue or feature.

Answer (score 2):

```
@For /f "tokens=1* delims=" %%A in ('reg query HKCR /f "URL:*" /s /d ^| findstr /c:"URL:" ^| findstr /v /c:"URL: " ^| Sort') Do @Echo %%A %%B
pause
```

If typing the above command, rather than in a batch file,  change `%%A` to `%A` and `%%B` to `%B`

will list all protocol handlers. It takes a while to run.

From the list `ms-quick-assist` and you add `://` to it so `ms-quick-assist://`.

Answer (score 2):

Are you saying, you are doing this:

```
Start-Process -FilePath 'calculator://'
```

You cannot have spaces in a Url/URI. The above works because it's a Windows App.

However, 'Quick Assist' is an executable, located here:

```
%windir%\system32\quickassist.exe
```

So, just type `quickassist` at cmd.exe shell or Powershell shell to launch it.

Answer (score 0):

You start Calculator in Windows Explorer by type calculator:// as you noted. That works.

**There is a Quick Assist** application but it, but as installed does not open like Calculator in Windows Explorer.

It will start the way any Windows App starts. So it does run.

You can get a Quick Assist app in the Microsoft Store to work like you wish. In Explorer, type quickassist:// (no spaces or dashes) and it will lead you there.